# Examples of statistical research affected by errors in package/library code

Tags: effect-size, software, research-design

I can't figure out if this belongs in Cross Validated, Stack Overflow, or Academia, but I think this may be a good place to start:

Can anyone suggest examples of published prospective/retrospective/cross-sectional research (particularly medical) where it was later discovered an uncaught error/bug in either the authors' statistical programming or in a package dependency resulted in an significantly different measure of effect than initially published?

Comment: Twitter might be the most appropriate venue?

Comment: Last week, during a two-day public workshop, the US Bureau of the Census disclosed the occurrence of a bug in their TopDown Algorithm for differential privacy (TDA) that caused some biases and substantially different standard errors in statistics developed from a demonstration dataset.  https://www.nationalacademies.org/event/06-21-2022/2020-census-data-products-workshop-on-the-demographic-and-housing-characteristics-files

Comment: @whuber Thank you! That's exactly the kind of thing I am looking for.